# asp.net core Taghelper merge with existing class attribute

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have a textbox with default class name, then wanna able to merge with new pass in class name.

I try created custom tag helper as below:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("input-form-control")]
public class FormControlTextBox : TagHelper
{
    private string ExtraClasses;

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("class", $"form-control {ExtraClasses}");
    }
}
```

How do I make it as my expected result as below:

```
<input class="form-control extra-class"></input>
```

Any better way to archive this?

Comment: I think your solution is ok.You can use SetAttribute or AddClass,the result is the same.

Comment: Can you show some demo code?